# No puedo correr mi app con ionic

Tags: angular, app, ionic-framework

Soy nuevo en el foro y en el mundo de ionic, empece hace poco a interesarme por el desarrollo de apps y me parecio una bueno opcion ionic, realice las instalaciones como lo indica en su pagina y al dar `ionic serve` me aparece lo siguiente.

```
[ng] Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "C:\\Users\\nikce\\documents\\project\\myapp\\myapp".
[ng] Error: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "C:\\Users\\nikce\\documents\\project\\myapp\\myapp".
[ng]     at Object.resolve (C:\Users\nikce\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node\resolve.js:141:11)
[ng]     at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable [as _subscribe] (C:\Users\nikce\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\src\architect.js:132:40)
[ng]     at Observable._trySubscribe (C:\Users\nikce\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:43:25)
[ng]     at Observable.subscribe (C:\Users\nikce\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:29:22)
[ng]     at DoOperator.call (C:\Users\nikce\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\tap.js:29:23)

[ng]     at Observable.subscribe (C:\Users\nikce\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:24:22)
[ng]     at C:\Users\nikce\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeTo.js:22:31
[ng]     at Object.subscribeToResult (C:\Users\nikce\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeToResult.js:7:45)
[ng]     at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (C:\Users\nikce\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:75:38)
[ng]     at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (C:\Users\nikce\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:72:14)

[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).
```

Trate de dar una solución pero no logro dar en la tecla con el problema de Angular pero no pude. Espero puedan ayudarme.

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.2.1 (C:\Users\nikce\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-beta.12
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : not installed
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : not installed
   @angular/cli                  : not installed
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : not installed


Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : not available
   Cordova Plugins       : not available

System:

   NodeJS : v8.12.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : Windows 10
```

**EDITADO**

Acabo de entrar a la página de Angular e instalar el CLI y construi una nueva app desde ionic usando `ionic start appName template --type=angular` y tambien el comando `ionic start appName template` pero el error persiste.

```
Angular CLI: 6.2.5
Node: 8.12.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.8.5
@angular-devkit/core         0.8.5
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.8.5
@schematics/angular          0.8.5
@schematics/update           0.8.5
rxjs                         6.2.2
typescript                   2.9.2
```

Comment: Para ingresar un comando como `ionic serve` en tu consola, debes tener en cuenta un parametro importante: primero debes construir tu aplicacion con el comando `ionic start` en la carpeta de tu preferencia (donde alamacenes tus aplicaciones) o puedes usar `ionic start tabs` para crear una plantilla de tipo `tabs` y luego que tengas todo el paquete completo puedes comenzar a correr el servicio de cordova `ionic serve` el cual posteriormente te abrirá una ventana de `localhost:3800` creo que ese el puerto que utiliza por defecto (puedo estar equivocado), esto a modo de comentario, sino me cuentas

Comment: Obviamente debes ingresar a la ruta de la misma aplicacion que has creado `cd documentos/miapp/` por ejemplo, y posteriormente usas los comandos que te he mencionado. Si es tu problema me lo haces saber para anadirlo como respuesta y mas no como un comentario.

Comment: Lo hice, construi el app utilizando `ionic start appName blank` luego le doy a `ionic serve` y me aparecen los errores, tambien la construi utilziando `ionic start nameApp blank --type=angular`, y el problema persiste. Gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Vale, que version de Ionic estás utilizando? `ionic --v`

Comment: En la pregunta estan las versiones que tengo instaladas y estoy utilziando

Comment: Si, no lo habia visto, disculpa!

Comment: Me ha pasado en Windows y me he dado cuenta que desactivando el antivirus momentaneamente corre el "ionic serve".

Answer (score 0):

> **Nota:** Lo siguiente es a modo de comentario para las personas que estén ingresando a este nuevo mundo de las aplicaciones híbridas.

Para ingresar un comando como `ionic serve` en tu consola, debes tener en cuenta un parametro importante:

1. Primero debes construir tu aplicacion con el comando `ionic start` en la carpeta de tu preferencia (donde alamacenes tus aplicaciones) o puedes usar `ionic start miApp tabs` para crear una plantilla de tipo `tabs`.
2. Luego que tengas todo el paquete completo puedes comenzar a correr el servicio de cordova `ionic serve` el cual posteriormente te abrirá una ventana de `localhost:8100` en tu navegador.

**Problemática**

Debes instalar `@angular-devkit/build-angular`, el cual está ligado en nuevas versiones como dependencia de desarrollo. ***Angular 6.X.X.***

Por lo que prueba con el siguiente comando para realizar la respectiva instalación de la dependencia:

**npm**

```
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

**yarn**

```
yarn add @angular-devkit/build-angular --dev
```

Y si esto no funciona te recomiendo que te muevas hasta tu carpeta, donde está tu aplicación y ejecutes el siguiente comando con `npm`:

```
npm install --save @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

Pruebas y me dices si soluciona tu problema

Comment: sigue sin funcionar, he probado con la app que ya esta creada e incluso cree una nueva

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente sea la versión de **Angular**, si no requieres de la **6.x.x** en especifico podrías intentar cambiándola por alguna más nueva o antigua.

Aunque tendrías que modificar tu archivo `package.json`, deberia de salirte algo como esto:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.8.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.8.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.2.5" <--aqui lo tienes que cambiar a otra versión, ejemplo: ~7.0.7
...}
```

Modificas el archivo especificando una versión diferente, como **~7.0.7**. Ahora ejecuta el comando de `npm uninstall @angular/cli` e instala de nuevo angular con

```
npm install -g angular-cli@~7.0.7
```